# Pushing new field into nested array

Tags: typescript

Im trying to push a new value into each array field. Any help would be appreciated?

```
export class class1 {
    value: number;
}

let class1 = new class1();

x: any[] = [];

for (var i = 0; i < result[nestedArray].length; i++) {                  
    this.x[i] = result["nestedArray"][i];
    class1.value = 5;
    this.x.push(class1.value)                   
}
```

I get `[{...}, {...}, {...}, 5]`

Im trying to add the `value` field from `class1` one into each nested array. But it seems to add just the 5 instead at the very end of the array.

Comment: push this.x[i].push(class1) or this.x[i].push({value:class1.value}) then

Comment: I get the error this.x[i].push is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `x[i]` instead of `x.push`. You  Do need to add `class1` or `{value:5}` to an object of an array like `[{a:1, value:5}, {b:1, value:5}]`. Use spread operator as below for that. 
Also you can assign `class1.value = 5` outside of the loop . as its the same.

```
let class1 = new Class1();

x: any[] = [];
class1.value = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < result["nestedArray"].length; i++) {                  
    this.x[i] = {...result["nestedArray"][i], ...class1};
}
```